# Activate Window from code problem

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, autoit, window-handles

I have a window on my desktop called: "Kaspersky Anti-Virus Configuration Wizard"

Here is some info about the window:

```
>>>> Window <<<<
Title:  Kaspersky Anti-Virus Configuration Wizard
Class:  AVP.ConfigureWizard
Position:   612, 247
Size:   499, 388
Style:  0x94CA0044
ExStyle:    0x00010100
Handle: 0x00081308
```

The window does not appear in the Windows Task Manager Tasks list (only it's process exists in processes list as "avp.exe" what, as far as i think, making it hard for me to acheive my goal. First of all i would appriciate that someone will explain how can Kaspersky Programmed i window that does not exists in "Application" Tab in "Windows Task Manager". Secondly I would be very thankful if you can help me solve my problem which is detailed here:

I want to make the window activeate (Set Focus on the window) from code (C++ \ Autoit).

I tried to use the FindWindow function of WinAPI but couldn't get the handle to this window.

I got the handle with GetForegroundWindow function and I've found out that when i use EnumWindows function the handle to kaspersky configuration window was not in the list..

this was my code:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(__in  HWND hwnd, __in  LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(g_hWnd == hwnd)
    {
        cout << "Found window";
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
BOOL CALLBACK EnumDesktopProc(
    __in  LPTSTR lpszDesktop,
    __in  LPARAM lParam
    )
{
    EnumDesktopWindows(OpenDesktop(lpszDesktop,DF_ALLOWOTHERACCOUNTHOOK,FALSE,DESKTOP_ALL),EnumWindowsProc, NULL);
    return true;
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowStationProc(
    __in  LPTSTR lpszWindowStation,
    __in  LPARAM lParam
    )
{
    EnumDesktops(OpenWindowStation(lpszWindowStation,FALSE, WINSTA_ALL_ACCESS),EnumDesktopProc, NULL );
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    Sleep(3000);
    g_hWnd = GetForegroundWindow(); //Here i switch to kaspersky window to get it's handle
    EnumWindowStations(EnumWindowStationProc, NULL);    //I call EnumDesktopWindows in EnumDesktops in EnumWindowStations to search in all HWND of my Operation System.
}
```

the cout << "Found Window" statement never executed.

I would be very grateful  if you could help me slove this and show me the ability to make this window active.

Comment: Do tell why you want to change Kaspersky configuration via script?

Comment: I make a program that will auto configure it.
but it doesn't really matter cause i do it for learning the same as i need it..

Comment: no one has figured out what is going on here?? I am stuck and i need you guys

Comment: Any anti-virus program worth it's salt is not going to allow 3rd party interaction in the traditional ways that's partially why you are having trouble no doubt ... you can use the Kaspersky Admin Kit possibly depending on the version you have and for learning purposes hack a web browser or easier target.

Comment: Try WinList Autoit function. The help file example, and see if it detects Kaspersky.

Comment: WinList won't show the window either..
It just can't be that i can get an handle to this window with GetForegroundWindor (Or GetWindowHandle('[ACTIVE'])) but i can't get it from a list...